# Passing optional argument in python

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to append a url by passing the parameters by commandline argument. Here is how I am trying:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Arguments')
parser.add_argument('input', metavar='input', type=str)
parser.add_argument('output', metavar='text', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
url = 'https://example.com/?z=12&text='+args.output+'&loc{}'
print url
```

When I execute

```
python url.py text.csv hello
```

It appends the second passed argument to the url. I want to know how to make the second argument optional so that even without providing the second argument I want the url to be printed by concatenating nothing to the url. Here is the output I am expecting:

When both arguments given:

```
python url.py text.csv hello
```

The output should be

```
https://example.com/?z=12&text=hello&loc{}
```

When single argument given

```
python url.py text.csv
```

The output should be

```
https://example.com/?z=12&text=&loc{}
```

Comment: Other than setting a default of `''`?

Comment: Setting default? Can you please explain @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. I am still learning.

Answer (score 6):

Try `nargs='?'` and define a `default`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Arguments')
parser.add_argument('input', metavar='input')
parser.add_argument('output', metavar='text', nargs='?', default='')
args = parser.parse_args()
url = 'https://example.com/?z=12&text='+args.output+'&loc{}'
print url
```

When I test it with just one commandline string, `args.output` is the default:

```
In [91]: args = parser.parse_args(['one'])

In [92]: args
Out[92]: Namespace(input='one', output='')

In [93]: args = parser.parse_args(['one','two'])

In [94]: args
Out[94]: Namespace(input='one', output='two')
```

It is best to only use `nargs='?'` (or '*' or '+') with the last positional argument.  It's possible to use it on earlier ones, but there are complications that can send you back with more questions.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have two options. Either you avoid using `argparse`altogether and go for something like:

```py
import sys
args_input  = sys.argv[1]
args_output = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else ''
url = 'https://example.com/?z=12&text='+args_output+'&loc{}'
print url
```

Or you add the `-` to your optional argument and, as [Ignacio's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857567/passing-optional-argument-in-python#comment63172773_37857567) suggests, you set a default empty value for the `output` argument:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Arguments')
parser.add_argument('input', metavar='input', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-output', metavar='text', type=str, default='')
args = parser.parse_args()
url = 'https://example.com/?z=12&text='+args.output+'&loc{}'
print url
```

With this second option you'll have to call it like:

```
python url.py text.csb -output hello
```

Or

```
python url.py text.csb
```

but it is more extensible if you want to add more arguments afterwards.

Comment: If first argument is always passed, it might be a cleaner syntax to only put a `-` in front of `output`. Then the program can be called with `python url.py text.csb -output hello` or `python url.py text.csb`

Comment: I completely agree! I was just thinking about that!!! I'll re-edit to show your suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: yea. thank you. I opted to add `-` to the second argument parser. I thought that would be easy addition than changing the rest of the code to `sys.argsv[]`. I did just like you said to another script using sys.argsv[] @jaumebonet . Thanks again to everyone. :)